# What is the best optimize way to check if array of arrays contains another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find an optimized way to check if an array of arrays contains another array.
Example:

```
const result = [['a','b','c'],['d']];
const sample = ['d'];
```

Here, result contains an array that matches sample array. How to optimize a *two for loop* solution with a length check?

```
for(let i = 0 ; i <result.length; i ++){
let arr = result[i];
if(arr.length === sample.length){
  for(let j = 0 ; j <sample.length; j ++){
      if(arr[j] !== sample[j]){
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
}
```

Looking for a faster way.

Comment: Not for performance-wise but maybe for readability. You can invert if to reduce nesting and you can use array functions like `every and some` and also you may add reference equality checking.

Comment: Your straightforward solution looks pretty good performance-wise. It will depend on the JIT, but IMHO it will be hard to come up with a faster implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do,

```
const result = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d']
];
const sample = ['d'];
const sample2 = ['a', 'b'];

console.log(result.some(r => JSON.stringify(r) == JSON.stringify(sample)))
console.log(result.some(r => JSON.stringify(r) == JSON.stringify(sample2)))
```

Comment: Why do you think it is faster? It might be more concise, but it has to do more work. I would expect it to be slower.

Comment: Yes true, given that is uses `JSON.stringify`. The solution was more biased towards the readability of the code